# @CreationTimestamp @UpdateTimestamp not available instantly after updating the entity class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having a `User` entity to which I am updating. The data got updated and even the updated response is returned by the `spring-data-jpa`'s `save` method, but the `created` and `updated` are null. I checked it in the database and `updated` column's value is updated one there. Also, after the update I got the data using one of the `find` methods by `spring-data-jpa` and I got the correct result. `created` and `updated` are not null this time.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateTimeSerializer;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;


    @Column(name = "created", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class) @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column(name = "updated")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class) @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime updated;
```

I can't blame the `save` method as it is returning me the other field's updated value. There might be something fishy in the working of `@UpdateTimestamp` and `@CreationTimestamp`, or with it's compatibility with `spring-data-jpa` I am not sure though.

One quick observation with `spring-data-jpa`: if I use `saveAndFlush` instead of `save`, I get `updated` as valid value, but `created` is still null. These are the screenshots of debug:

[image: save]
[image: saveAndFlush]

I am using `Hibernate` as the `JPA` implementation.

```
public interface CompanyDao extends CrudRepository<Company, Integer> { }


public User update(Integer userId, User user) {

    User existingUser = userDao.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found"));

    user.setCompany(existingUser.getCompany());

    User updatedUser = userDao.save(user);

    return updatedUser;
}
```

Comment: The pertinent code will be that where you update and save the entity so add that.

Comment: @AlanHay updated the details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` annotations from Spring.

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User {

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

}
```

To do this you need to annotate your spring config with annotation `@EnableJpaAuditing`

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
}
```